# replace 0 and -ve values with r and convert from hourly to daily

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have one file with 38 columns and 78880 rows. Some columns have 0 and negative values. I want to replace 0 and negative values with NaN in all the columns.

I tried

```
replace(new_file, which(new_file <= 0), NA)
```

But it's not working.

After That, the given file is in hourly data. So I need to convert into daily and save all the 38 columns in a new file with date (YYYY-MM-DD).

```
Date       Var1  Var2  Var3  ......
2009-01-01  
2009-01-02
2009-01-03
```

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: what do you mean by `-ve`?

Comment: -ve means negative values

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: For point 1 try something like `dat[dat$var <= 0, ]$var <- NA`

Comment: I can easily change -negative values with NaN for ONE column using    replace(new_file$var, which(new_file$var <= 0, ), NA). But, I want to apply this function to multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

First let's create some dummy data:

```
N <- 10
df <- data.frame(Date=rep("2018-09-18", N), 
                 Var1=rnorm(N), 
                 Var2=rnorm(N), 
                 Var3=rnorm(N))
df
```

Looks like:

```
         Date      Var1      Var2       Var3
1  2018-09-18  0.7806645  1.06439912 -0.82916929
2  2018-09-18  0.8206491  2.22059077 -0.12357957
3  2018-09-18 -0.4384802  0.56787833  0.50516721
4  2018-09-18 -0.5979955  0.10862365  0.42544565
```

Now let's write a function to deal with one column (i.e. a vector).
`ifelse` is handy because it is already *vectorized*.

```
# Function handling one vector
fix_negative_values <- function(vec) {
  ifelse(vec > 0, vec, NA)
}
```

Using `dplyr` for easy data manipulation, we apply `fix_negative_values` to all columns apart from Date.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-Date), fix_negative_values)
```

This gives:

```
         Date      Var1      Var2       Var3
1  2018-09-18 0.7806645 1.0643991         NA
2  2018-09-18 0.8206491 2.2205908         NA
3  2018-09-18        NA 0.5678783 0.50516721
4  2018-09-18        NA 0.1086236 0.42544565
```

If you want to turn hourly data into daily data, you will find `dplyr` useful as you can `group_by(date)` and then `summarize_at(vars(-Date), funs(mean(., na.rm=T)))` to get daily average.